# Remove \r from a json

Tags: python, json

How can I remove \r when returning json object?? I tried to create an API using Flask, but json object which returns by the API always contain \r as follows.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "CLOSE\r": "1.16386\r", 
            "DTYYYYMMDD": "20170726", 
            "HIGH": "1.1639", 
            "LOW": "1.16386", 
            "OPEN": "1.16389", 
            "TIME": "0705"
        }, 
        {
            "CLOSE\r": "1.16385\r", 
            "DTYYYYMMDD": "20170726", 
            "HIGH": "1.16387", 
            "LOW": "1.16385", 
            "OPEN": "1.16386", 
            "TIME": "0706"
        }
]}
```

my python code looks like

```
class GetPriceData(Resource):
 def get(self, date):  # param is pulled from url string
    conn = e.connect()
    query = conn.execute("select * from pricedata where DTYYYYMMDD='%s'" % date.upper())
    result = {'data': [dict(zip(tuple(query.keys()), i)) for i in query.cursor]}
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try by modifying result assignment line:

```
result = {'data': [dict(zip(tuple(query.keys().replace("\r","")), i.replace("\r",""))) for i in query.cursor]}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but it gives an error as "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'"